# How to handle excel file sent in POST request in Django?

Tags: python, django, pandas, http-post

I sent an excel file in a post request to my back-end and I tried handling the file using the following:

```
def __handle_file(file):
destination = open('./data.xslx', 'wb')
for chunk in file.chunks():
    destination.write(chunk)
destination.close()
```

However, the output from that is not an excel file. It is a collection of XML files.
My end goal is to obtain a data frame from the file data that was sent so that I can extract the data.

What is a clean way of handling this type of file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_data = request.FILES[KEY].file
```

Returns the file uploaded in the form of bytes.
The following will read the excel file as a data frame:

```
data = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(file_data.read()))
```